# How to add a directory to the $PATH variable with macosx leopard

Tags: macos, path, environment-variables

I really am unable to add a directory to the `$PATH` variable. I have tried to add a text file to `etc/paths.d/` containing the path I want to add, but the OS refuses to let me add a file to that directory (permission denied). I don't know why, since I log in as admin...

Please help me, I need to add the `adb` path for the Android SDK on macosx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permissions on /etc/paths.d only allow the root account to write to it, not normal admins.  This is actually fairly common in OS X, since many users operate day-to-day as admins, but for security reasons it's a bad idea for them to have write access to any settings that can influence system integrity without going through an explicit I-mean-to-do-that step.

So how can you add a file?  In general, you need to use a process that promotes to root to do the operation.  I'll give three examples:

1. Create the file someplace else, then use the Finder to move it into place.  Since /etc is normally invisible, in the Finder, you'll need to explicitly open it by choosing Go > Go to Folder from the menu, then entering "/etc/paths.d".  Then just drag the file into that window, and it'll ask for your admin password (which it uses to promote to root and move the file).
2. Use [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/download.html) or its big brother, [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) (the download version, not the Mac App Store version).  They have built-in capability to safe files as root (after entering your admin password, just like Finder).  If you're going to be manipulating system config files on a regular basis, this is (IMHO) the easiest option.
3. At the command line, you can use `sudo` as a prefix to run a command as root (again, after entering your admin password), e.g. `sudo cp mypathfile /etc/paths.d` or `sudo vi /etc/paths.d/mypathfile`.