# jenkins on Mac, PATH is not set right, no /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, jenkins, homebrew, launchd

I recently installed Jenkins, using Homebrew. I also installed Mercurial using Homebrew.

I can successfully clone an hg repo just fine - from Terminal. But if I try and do the same thing as part of a job in Jenkins, it fails.

So, in by job, I told Jenkins to run a shell script `echo $PATH`. Sure enough, the path `/usr/local/bin` is not there. If I execute the same command from Terminal, it's there.

**So, what is the best way to modify PATH so that Jenkins is pulling the same PATH that I'm using, when I echo it from Terminal?**

Note, Jenkins is running from the same user account that I'm logged into doing these tests, so I can't fathom why this is happening.

Comment: also, I'm having jenkins run from my account using launchd. So, whenever my account "logs in", it powers up Jenkins.

Comment: +1, I thought I was losing my marbles, glad it's not just me.  This never used to happen in older versions, is it a new "feature"??

Answer (score 23):

In your launchd .plist file for Jenkins, you can set the PATH environment variable by using the following:

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>(insert your path value here)</string>
</dict>
```

That should set the PATH to whatever you need.

Comment: Can the value be "$PATH:/my/other/path"? I need to append to path.

Comment: I don't believe so.   As far as I know the $PATH interpretation is done by the shell and that's not going to get run though for this setting method, so you need to give a full path list here.

Comment: To clarify my above comment. As far as I know "$PATH" interpretation is something that is normally done by the shell, and thus won't be used as expansion for the launchd .plist file.   Therefore, you should give a full path list of the form "/foo/bar/zot:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/whatever/you/want/"

Comment: Thank you! It's amazing this is not listed more often. I was having so many issues trying to get the jenkins path set right.

Comment: Basically at the top level of the plist.  If you don't know the format of the file, you should `man plist` from terminal to see the details, but basically it alternates between key and value.

Comment: I tried this for a Jenkins slave on OSX 10.10, but the for whatever reason the PATH wouldn't change. I could set other variables... but not PATH. Eventually, I just set PATH as an environment variable in the Jenkins node configuration.

Comment: After executing `brew services restart jenkins`, the configuration will be reset.

Comment: @gagarine You'd insert this just inside the root level `<plist ...><dict>` tag. A good example is here: http://serverfault.com/a/128693/1687

Comment: This helped when I changed my `JENKINS_HOME` path. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is good, but it could be improved by adding the full snipped of the plist, so people knows exactly where to insert the `EnvironmentVariables` key and don't get it wrong. Also it could mention where the plist is located, at least if a brew installation was meant. Mine was at `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist`

Answer (score 14):

For some reason, Jenkins doesn't keep /usr/local/bin in the PATH when connecting to a slave.
You can add it to the PATH either by

- Adding an environment variable on the Node Configuration, or
- Adding a .bashrc file on the user folder with

  ```
   PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
  ```

Note: The Mac client must be disconnected and then reconnected via the Jenkins web app after editing ~/.bashrc

Comment: Editing the .bashrc file didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: However, editing .bash_profile for the jenkins user on the Node did the trick for getting the path visible in the `sh` block of a Jenkinsfile

Comment: I spent total 3 days, and at the end this worked, and helped me to run my jenkins job from windows(master) to macos(slave). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I found that even setting the PATH environment variable for the node didn't work for the hombrew Mercurial installation. The path WOULD get set, but only for the script build phase, not for the VCS checkout phase. Here's what I wound up doing.

1. Go into `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System`
2. Add a new Mercurial Installation
3. Name it whatever you want (I named mine build-mac)
4. For `Installation Directory` I put `/usr/local`
5. The `Executable` parameter was pre-set to `INSTALLATION/bin/hg`, so I just left it at that.
6. Everything else in here can be left blank
7. Go into your job and edit the configuration
8. Under `Source Code Management` set `Mercurial Version` to the mercurial installation you just added.
9. Save
10. $$$

Hope that helps anyone else running into this same problem, now that we're not allowed (by default anyways) to do anything inside of `/usr/bin` anymore. Previously I would have just symlinked hg there, but now with the new "System Integrity Protection" "feature", that's no longer as trivial of task, and even more difficult if your Mac slave is headless.

Answer (score 3):

You can set PATH in launchd.conf file. See [here](http://overwatering.org/blog/2012/08/setting-path-osx-mountain-lion/) for details. Note that `man launchctl` says that 'commands can be stored in $HOME/.launchd.conf or /etc/launchd.conf to be read at the time launchd starts', so you probably can create '.launchd.conf' in your home directory and use instructions from the link with this file. But as far as I know in launchd.conf file you can't add directory to PATH, you can just rewrite PATH.

You can also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910229/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path-variable-with-macosx-leopard) for the solution using /etc/paths.d directory

Comment: `/etc/launchd.conf` appears to be deprecated as of OSX 10.10. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26311753/331041

Answer (score 3):

There should be no space on either side of = in following PATH modification:
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

I added it to my pre-build step on Jenkins installed on macOS.

Comment: Adding `PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` to the  pre-build step worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Environment variables -> Add

- Name = PATH+EXTRA
- Value = /usr/local/bin

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant and worked for me easily and flawlessly!  Where is this documented?  I can't find it anywhere but it worked like a charm.  Was struggling with this for some time and this was a solution like none other.  I was hesitant to try any modification at the macOS or Homebrew levels since I upgrade Jenkins almost weekly.  How did you discover this?  So excited to find out that Jenkins has this type of "secret menu" configurations! :D