# Jenkins unable to find Hg

Tags: jenkins, mercurial

I'm setting up Jenkins on a Mac, and we use Mercurial (Hg).
Jenkins and Hg are both installed.  I can run Hg from the command line.
It is located in /usr/local/bin

I've used the Jenkins Global Tool to set the location of Hg. I've tried all kinds of combinations of Installation Directory and executable to specify that path.
None of them work.

- /usr/local and INSTALLATION/bin/hg
- /usr/local/bin and hg
- blank and /usr/local/bin/hg

I've found LOTS of reports of this kind of problem, all several years old, none of which seem to provide a solution.

This is the error I receive:

```
11:11:00 $ hg clone --rev 2017_2 --noupdate ssh://hg@xxxxx:2525/repos/reponame /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/App_2017_2
11:11:00 ERROR: Failed to clone ssh://hg@xxxxx:2525/repos/reponame because hg could not be found; check that you've properly configured your Mercurial installation
```

I'm assuming that I must be doing something incredibly obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer at [jenkins on Mac, PATH is not set right, no /usr/local/bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620369/jenkins-on-mac-path-is-not-set-right-no-usr-local-bin)
(the one down near the bottom from Jordan Bondo)

After setting up the paths for Hg in "Global Tool Configuration" (note: do NOT just name your Mercurial setup "Mercurial", use some other name.)
I then had to go to the Build configuration and explicitly tell it to use that specific Mercurial configuration.