# Build Failed: NPM: command not found - ReactJS project

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I am absolute beginner in Jenkins started learning from yesterday. I went through theory session yesterday that went quit well. However, on when I am trying hands on it I stuck with probably petty issue for Jenkins user.

I am running Jenkins on my mac machine and it's a completely brand new setup

**here is the error**

```
+ echo 'build start...'
build start...
[first-job] $ /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins2233817479314329111.sh
+ npm install
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins2233817479314329111.sh: line 2: npm: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Project config.

[image]

Comment: I have not used Jenkins, but looks like build environment does not have npm installed. Before running `npm install` make sure that `npm` itself is installed and is in your `$PATH` in Jenkins environment

Comment: Potentially. How and where to define ```$PATH``` in Jenkins environment

Comment: I assume you installed node on your jenkins machine?  How did you install it?

Comment: @JimB. I am running jenkins on mac machine and I have install nodejs through ```brew``` command

Comment: If you can run npm in your own account but it doesn't work within Jenkins, it's probably because Jenkins is running your jobs under a different user (jenkins).  Brew puts installed files in /usr/local/bin/...  Make sure /usr/local/bin is in the path for the jenkins user.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620369/jenkins-on-mac-path-is-not-set-right-no-usr-local-bin

Comment: This may help too: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin